# Cannot use OR Operator

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm trying to use the `OR` operator in my message controller to show conversation.  I have tried two statements I found in here, but neither of them is working.

1st one:

```
@messages = current_user.messages.where(:sender_id => params[:sender_id]).OR(:reciptient_id => params[:sender_id])
```

> ERROR: Or method not found

2nd one:

```
@messages = current_user.messages.where("sender_id = :sender_id OR recipient_id = :sender_id", {sender_id => params[:sender_id], :recipient_id => params[:sender_id]})
```

> Error: undefined local variable or method sender_id

I'm using Rails 3.2. Could someone tell me what's wrong in my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second one is almost right, there is just a slight typo in it. It shoul be like this:

```
@messages = current_user.messages.where("sender_id = :sender_id OR recipient_id = :sender_id", 
{:sender_id => params[:sender_id], :recipient_id => params[:sender_id]})
```

You missed the ":" before the sender_id.